# Why is SHELL pointed to /bin/sh in a Csh script?

Tags: shell, cron, environment-variables, tcsh, csh

Yes, I know C-shell is bad.  No, I did not choose C-shell.  Yes, I would prefer to use a proper shell.  No, I cannot switch to a better shell.

I have a very simplistic script:

/tmp/env_test.csh

```
#!/bin/csh -f

env
```

When I run this script from my user that is logged in with a tcsh shell, `SHELL` equals `/bin/tcsh`.  When I run this script from cron, `SHELL` equals `/bin/sh`.

Why is the SHELL not being updated appropriately?  What do I need to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why is it an issue anyway?

Comment: @muru after stumbling through this and finding a solution, it appears it's an issue because perlbrew doesn't apparently appropriately "sense" the shell is [t]csh if `$SHELL` is not set to the correct shell. When cron is running using `/bin/sh`, `$SHELL=/bin/sh`, even after launching a C-shell script (`#!/bin/csh -f`). Perlbrew then assumes it's a Bourne shell and uses Bourne shell commands to set up the environment. This happens despite running `source <perlbrew path>/perlbrew/etc/cshrc` prior to running `perlbrew use`. I solved this by inserting `setenv SHELL /bin/csh` to the perlbrew cshrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `man 1 csh`. The section `Pre-defined and environment variables` lists which variables `csh` defines or respects. There is a variable `shell` in lowercase:

```
     shell      The file in which the shell resides.  This variable is used in
                forking shells to interpret files that have execute bits set,
                but which are not executable by the system.  (See the descrip-
                tion of Non-builtin Command Execution below.)  Initialized to
                the (system-dependent) home of the shell.
```

So let's have a look:

```
% echo $shell
/bin/csh
```

Comment: So from what I can tell after a number of tests, $shell is not a true environment variable, but rather a shell-interpreted variable.  `echo $shell` returns `/bin/tcsh` from the script, but `env | grep -i shell` does not find the correct variable in cron.  It was my understanding from other places (such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3327022/1463788)) that `$SHELL` should be set.  Indeed, in my active login shell, it is.  The only place I don't get `$SHELL` is cron.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `SHELL` variable to `/bin/csh` in your crontrab, you can check the cron environment variable through:

```
* * * * * env > ~/cron-env
tail -f ~/cron-env
```

The default `SHELL` should be set to `/bin/sh`.

[SO: How to simulate the environment cron executes a script with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with)